# How to combine the rows of two different tables into the same column?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have 2 tables, both with an employee_id and a task_group column. I need to build a query that returns a list of all the task_groups associated with a particular employee_id, whether they exist in either table.

Example:

```
Table 1:
Emp_ID | Blah_Blah
1234   | junk
6969   | crap

Table 2:
Emp_ID | Blah_Blah
1234   | crud
1234   | poop
```

And I need to build a query that will return this:

```
Query:
Blah_Blah
junk
crud
poop
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Blah_Blah from Table1 WHERE <some condition>
UNION
SELECT Blah_Blah from Table2 WHERE <some contition>
```

Comment: Glorious! I forgot about the UNION command. You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Select blah_blah
From Table1
Where Emp_ID = 1234
Union All
Select blah_blah
From Table2
Where Emp_ID = 1234
```

If the same value for `blah_blah` exists in both tables, the above will result in a duplicate. If you want to eliminate duplicates, then use Union instead of Union All:

```
Select blah_blah
From Table1
Where Emp_ID = 1234
Union 
Select blah_blah
From Table2
Where Emp_ID = 1234
```